# Sharepoint passing parameter from one list to another

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer

I have 2 Sharepoint lists. I want to send ID number from one list to another which can be used as a filter value in second list. So when I click on text of issue list, it should go to another list which shows all the issues related to corresponding ID number.

I am using Sharepoint 2013 and Sharepoint 2013 Designer.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create ID number as a lookup column.

See:
Create list relationships by using unique and lookup columns

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-help/create-list-relationships-by-using-unique-and-lookup-columns-HA102771358.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your quick response but the lookup brings information from the target list into source list view. My second list is issue list so I want to show all the issues for that particular ID but currently I am getting only one issue. So, how to get multiple records for that particular ID from issue lists?

Comment: you can create a page, add both of your list and connect 2 webparts with id column. Check out http://blog.splibrarian.com/2012/05/21/connecting-web-parts-with-a-selector-and-a-detail-pane-sharepoint-2010-version/